# Why are my items not being sorted (re-rendered) in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a button that when clicked calls a function that sorts the products by case amount.  I am updating the products array so I assumed this would trigger a re-render of the products being mapped in the code below but it is not.  Does anyone know how to get this to trigger the products.map to be re-rendered again thus displaying the new sorted products?

```
render() {
    const {products} = this.props;
    const cartIcon = (<Icon name="shopping-cart"  style={styles.cartIcon} />);

    sortCartItems = () => {
        products.sort((a, b) => a.cases > b.cases);
    }

    return (            
        <View style={styles.itemsInCartContent}>
            <View style={styles.cartHeader}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={sortCartItems}>
                    {cartIcon}
                    <Text>Sort</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            {products.map((product, index) =>
                <CartProductItem
                    ref="childCartProductItem"
                    key={product.id}
                    product={product}
                    index={index}
                    activeIndex={this.state.active}
                    triggerParentUpdate={() => this.collapseAllOtherProducts}
                />
            )}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Maybe the state needs to change?

Comment: change `onPress={sortCartItems}` to `onPress={this.sortCartItems.bind(this)}` and `sortCartItems = () => {
        products.sort((a, b) => a.cases > b.cases);
    }` to `sortCartItems = () => {
        products.sort((a, b) => a.cases > b.cases); this.forceUpdate();
    }`

Comment: @messerbill This is an antipattern. You should never mutate props and `forceUpdate` is not intended to be used like this. React provides stateful components for that.

Answer (score 2):

A component should not mutate it's own props. [If your data changes during the lifetime of a component you need to use `state`.](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#an-interactive-component)

Your inline arrow function `sortCartItems` tries to mutate the `products` that come from props. Your need to store the products in the components state instead and call `setState` to change them which will trigger a re-render.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            products: props.products,
        }
    }

    sortCartItems = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({products: prevState.products.sort((a, b) => a.cases > b.cases);}))
    }

    render() {...}
}
```

Note that you need to use a callback in `setState` whenever you are updating the state based on the previous state. The callback receives the old state as a parameter and returns the new state.

Comment: Sadly it's encouraged not to explain downvotes (to stop retaliation). Maybe consider adding an example of what the OP could do instead?

Comment: I have linked section in the react tutorial that explains in detail how to use state in react. The asker obviously did no research at all because this is one of the most basic things in react to do. I don't know why I should copy the react documentation here.

Comment: I downvoted this accidently! Corrected my mistake ;)

Comment: @evolutionxbox It is not encouraged to explain downvotes? Whenever I downvote a question it displays a banner asking me to add a comment that explains what I think is wrong/should be improved. Where did you take that information from? It's just a good habit to explain yourself. Apart from that in this case the downvote was an accident.

Comment: I've been encouraged multiple times not explain a downvote, but instead comment to help improve a question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes/2373#2373

Comment: @evolutionxbox Isn't that basically the same thing except you do not start your comment with: "I downvoted because..." ?

Comment: (essentially, but don't tell anyone I said that...)

Comment: @evolutionxbox agreed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of messerbill's and trixn's answers to come up with the following which is now working.  And I added a products property to state which receives its data from props.products

```
render() {
    const cartIcon = (<Icon name="shopping-cart"  style={styles.cartIcon} />);

    sortCartItems = () => {
        this.setState({
            products: this.state.products.sort((a, b) => a.cases > b.cases)
        });
    }

    return (            
        <View style={styles.itemsInCartContent}>
            <View style={styles.cartHeader}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={sortCartItems}>
                    {cartIcon}
                    <Text>Sort</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            {this.state.products.map((product, index) =>
                <CartProductItem
                    ref="childCartProductItem"
                    key={product.id}
                    product={product}
                    index={index}
                    activeIndex={this.state.active}
                    triggerParentUpdate={() => this.collapseAllOtherProducts}
                />
            )}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: @trixn is not completley wrong with what he said....`forceUpdate()` should not be used if not necessary but sometimes i also do not know how to solve it otherwise (due to i am also quite new to react) and this works....but you "pay" with performance here

Comment: This is much better but you should use `setState()` instead of mutating the state object directly.

Comment: Ah ok I have updated it to use setState() and it works!

Comment: @Tanya I added an example to my answer.

Comment: @messerbill I am using react for quite a long time now and in decently sized projects and never had to use `forceUpdate`. It can all be done with `props` and `state`. If you find yourself using it frequently you are probably not doing it the react way.

Comment: @trixn isn't a `forceUpdate()` simply a `setState()` to all property and state attributes?

Comment: @messerbill No what is it does is manually triggering a re-render by also skipping `shouldComponentUpdate`. It does literally what it's name says. Nothing will be mutated by calling it. But of course if you mutated the `state` or `props` yourself before it will cause the component to render the mutated state. The problem is react doesn't know about what you mutate directly and can also not batch multiple state changes to prevent unnecessary re-renders.